# Windows server time keeps setting the time 2 hours back

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, ntp, time-synchronization

Our Windows 2012 server keeps setting its system clock 2 hours back. 
I've tried to run 'w32tm /resync' a couple of times but that does only works on short term.

the server manager gives an Error with ID 36 and the following description:

> The time service has not synchronized the system time for 86400
>   seconds because none of the time service providers provided a usable
>   time stamp. The time service will not update the local system time
>   until it is able to synchronize with a time source. If the local
>   system is configured to act as a time server for clients, it will stop
>   advertising as a time source to clients. The time service will
>   continue to retry and sync time with its time sources. Check system
>   event log for other W32time events for more details. Run 'w32tm
>   /resync' to force an instant time synchronization.

Also 'w32tm /query /source' gives me :

> Free-running System Clock

Its a physical server so no VMWare involved. It's our SQL Data server and data keeps coming in tough the timestamps are off because of the wrong server time. Tough data keeps coming in so it can't be a network problem

Comment: Is it joined to an AD domain?

Comment: Its a standalone server just used for progressing large amounts of data between devices and our Filemaker server running on a MAC

Comment: Any change if you set the time service to sync from an external NTP server? `w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:”pool.ntp.org,time.windows.com” /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update`

Comment: Currently trying that, will reply if i know more